# Why is validation_binary_accuracy so smooth/continuous compared to accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am building a neural network in Keras to classify some input data with a binary classifier:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005), input_shape=(feature_vector_length,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
    optimizer='rmsprop', 
    loss='binary_crossentropy', 
    metrics=[
        'accuracy', 
        keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name="binary_accuracy", dtype=None, threshold=0.5)
    ]
)
```

This is how I train my model:

```
history = model.fit(
    partial_x_train, 
    partial_y_train, 
    epochs=500, 
    validation_split=0.2
)
```

The following are a few epochs of training:

```
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1267 - accuracy: 0.9699 - binary_accuracy: 0.8534 - val_loss: 1.4187 - val_accuracy: 0.7027 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8533
Epoch 277/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0821 - accuracy: 0.9945 - binary_accuracy: 0.8533 - val_loss: 1.2855 - val_accuracy: 0.7177 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8533
Epoch 278/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0721 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.8533 - val_loss: 1.2802 - val_accuracy: 0.7027 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8533
Epoch 279/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0733 - accuracy: 0.9982 - binary_accuracy: 0.8533 - val_loss: 1.4469 - val_accuracy: 0.7297 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8534
Epoch 280/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1879 - accuracy: 0.9708 - binary_accuracy: 0.8533 - val_loss: 1.1390 - val_accuracy: 0.7387 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8533
Epoch 281/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0791 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.8533 - val_loss: 1.1721 - val_accuracy: 0.7417 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8534
Epoch 282/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0724 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.8534 - val_loss: 1.1854 - val_accuracy: 0.7327 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8535
Epoch 283/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0749 - accuracy: 0.9987 - binary_accuracy: 0.8534 - val_loss: 1.4045 - val_accuracy: 0.7267 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8535
Epoch 284/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1645 - accuracy: 0.9617 - binary_accuracy: 0.8534 - val_loss: 1.1953 - val_accuracy: 0.7417 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8535
Epoch 285/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0752 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.8535 - val_loss: 1.2235 - val_accuracy: 0.7387 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8535
Epoch 286/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0697 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.8535 - val_loss: 1.2226 - val_accuracy: 0.7417 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 287/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0790 - accuracy: 0.9992 - binary_accuracy: 0.8536 - val_loss: 1.4077 - val_accuracy: 0.6907 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 288/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2251 - accuracy: 0.9440 - binary_accuracy: 0.8535 - val_loss: 1.2639 - val_accuracy: 0.7297 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8535
Epoch 289/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0884 - accuracy: 0.9883 - binary_accuracy: 0.8535 - val_loss: 1.2017 - val_accuracy: 0.7207 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8535
Epoch 290/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0732 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.8535 - val_loss: 1.2063 - val_accuracy: 0.7267 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 291/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0723 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.8535 - val_loss: 1.2171 - val_accuracy: 0.7357 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 292/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0714 - accuracy: 0.9995 - binary_accuracy: 0.8536 - val_loss: 1.6722 - val_accuracy: 0.6997 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 293/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1404 - accuracy: 0.9821 - binary_accuracy: 0.8536 - val_loss: 1.1662 - val_accuracy: 0.7117 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 294/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0989 - accuracy: 0.9882 - binary_accuracy: 0.8535 - val_loss: 1.2021 - val_accuracy: 0.7177 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 295/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0719 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.8536 - val_loss: 1.2035 - val_accuracy: 0.7237 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 296/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0710 - accuracy: 0.9995 - binary_accuracy: 0.8536 - val_loss: 1.8040 - val_accuracy: 0.6997 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 297/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2135 - accuracy: 0.9765 - binary_accuracy: 0.8536 - val_loss: 1.2538 - val_accuracy: 0.7387 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 298/500
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0973 - accuracy: 0.9909 - binary_accuracy: 0.8536 - val_loss: 1.4476 - val_accuracy: 0.7057 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8536
```

[image]

1. Something is weird with my accuracy metrics. Notice how the `binary_accuracy` and `val_binary_accuracy` increase smoothly... I only have 666 training examples, 20% of which are in my validation set -- So the split is  533 (training set) 133 (validation set), so I would expect the accuracy to vary in steps of `0.0018 = 1/533` (training set) and `0.007 = 1/113`, but it can be seen going up in steps of 0.0001.
2. Accuracy, which assesses if predictions == labels, should be much, much lower... considering all of my labels are `0` or `1`, and the predictions are probabilities **between** `0` and `1`. So, the only way to actually get a correct prediction by the accuracy metric is if my model predicts `1.000` or `0.000` which is extremely rare

I'm achieving `val_binary_accuracy` rates that are quite high in some of my models, so I am quite skeptical and want to know what I'm potentially doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but it seems that your val_accuracy is much more volatile than your val_binary_accuracy which is more what you would expect so maybe this is due to a property of val_binary_accuracy

Comment: I don't understand how Keras can decide after an epoch that the model is `0.0001%` more accurate on the validation set when 1/113 samples gives a minimum increase of `0.007` :/. Accuracy seems to vary by an appropriate step size but not binary_accuracy

Comment: Could it be possible that BinaryAccuracy did not update it's total and count variable between batches which would stabilize the values a lot more? Although it would not explain why the values are higher that validation_accuracy

Comment: I do not doubt that binary_accuracy would be much higher than accuracy for my model-- but I agree with you, it feels like it is cumulative across all epochs up to that epoch or something... maybe I need to bug report?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing binary accuracy increase by 0.0001?

Comment: Also note that training and validation metrics are not computed in the same way, training metrics are running means of per-batch metrics.

Comment: If you scroll all the way over to the right in my training log output, you will see validation_binary_accuracy (and binary_accuracy) go up from 0.8533 to 0.8534 to 0.8535 to 0.8536 and so on. So are you saying the accuracy value reported is the mean across all batches during the epoch? Because then it might make sense!

Comment: No, validation  metrics are not a running mean (this is not the same as a mean over all batches). Note too that all metrics computations happen in floating point, meaning that there are imprecision errors (and the displayed numbers are rounded to 4 digits).